# ¿Cómo guardar una imagen en una carpeta del servidor en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo este código HTML:

```
 <div id="container">
   <div id="calendar">
   </div>
 </div>
<button class="btn btn-dark mb-1" onclick="captureAndSave()">Formato</button>
```

Y este código JS:

```
 <script>

  function captureAndSave() 
  {
    // Selecciona el elemento "calendar"
    var elementToCapture = document.querySelector('section.content');

    // Oculta los elementos con la clase ".noPrint" utilizando CSS
    var elementsToHide = elementToCapture.querySelectorAll('.noPrint');
    elementsToHide.forEach(function(element)
    {
      element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });

    // Utiliza html2canvas para capturar una imagen del elemento modificado
    html2canvas(elementToCapture).then(function(canvas) 
    {
      // Convierte el lienzo en una imagen codificada en base64
      var imageBase64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      // Restaura la visibilidad de los elementos con la clase ".noPrint"
      elementsToHide.forEach(function(element) 
      {
        element.style.visibility = 'visible';
      });

      // Crea un elemento <a> para descargar la imagen
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = imageBase64;
      link.download = 'captura.png';

      // Dispara el evento de clic para descargar la imagen
      link.click();
    });
  }

</script>
```

Se supone que al presionar el botón se descarga una imagen del contenido "section.content", ¿cierto? Pues efectivamente se efectúa dicha acción, pero al tratar de adaptar ese ejemplo y hacer que en lugar de descargarse en el equipo del usuario, se descargue en una carpeta del servidor, no lo logro.

Intenté este acercamiento:

Código JS modificado:

```
<script>

function captureAndSave() 
{
  var elementToCapture = document.querySelector('section.content');

  var elementsToHide = elementToCapture.querySelectorAll('.noPrint');
  elementsToHide.forEach(function (element) {
    element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  });

  html2canvas(elementToCapture).then(function (canvas) {
    var imageBase64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    elementsToHide.forEach(function (element) {
      element.style.visibility = 'visible';
    });

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'assets/imagen.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    var data = 'image=' + encodeURIComponent(imageBase64);
    xhr.send(data);

    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (response.success) {
          alert(response.message);
        } else {
          alert('Error: ' + response.message);
        }
      }
    };
  });
}

</script>
```

Código PHP llamado "imagen.php" que intenté para gestionar el guardado en el servidor sin éxito:

```
<?php
$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['image'])) 
{
  // Obtén la imagen codificada en base64 desde la solicitud
  $imageData = $_POST['image'];

  // Define la ruta y el nombre de archivo donde guardar la imagen
  $filePath = '../vistas/img/temp/imagen.png';

  // Guarda la imagen en la carpeta deseada
  if(file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $imageData)))) 
  {
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'La imagen se ha guardado correctamente.';
  } 
  else 
  {
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'Hubo un error al guardar la imagen.';
  }
} 
else 
{
  $response['success'] = false;
  $response['message'] = 'No se recibió ninguna imagen.';
}

  // Devuelve la respuesta en formato JSON
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia en qué podría cambiar o de algún mejor acercamiento a lo que quiero lograr? De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verifica que la ruta del archivo de destino en el código PHP sea correcta. En el código PHP, se define la variable $filePath que especifica la ruta y el nombre de archivo donde se guardará la imagen. Asegúrate de que la ruta sea válida y accesible para el servidor. Si la carpeta ../vistas/img/temp/ no existe, crea la carpeta manualmente o asegúrate de que la estructura de carpetas sea correcta.
2. Asegúrate de que la carpeta de destino tenga los permisos adecuados para que el servidor pueda escribir en ella. Verifica los permisos de la carpeta temp y asegúrate de que el servidor web tenga permisos de escritura en ella. Puedes cambiar los permisos de la carpeta mediante comandos de terminal o utilizando un cliente FTP.
3. Verifica si hay mensajes de error. Puedes habilitar la visualización de errores en PHP agregando el siguiente código al principio de tu script PHP:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Esto te ayudará a identificar cualquier error que pueda estar ocurriendo durante el proceso de guardado de la imagen.

Asegúrate de que la solicitud AJAX esté enviando los datos correctamente. Puedes agregar algunos mensajes de depuración en el código JavaScript para verificar si el valor de imageBase64 se está pasando correctamente en la solicitud POST. Por ejemplo, puedes agregar

```
console.log(imageBase64);
```

antes de enviar la solicitud AJAX para imprimir el valor en la consola del navegador y verificar si contiene los datos de la imagen codificados en base64.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".